docker: if "--gpus 0", do we still need to run on GPU / NVIDIA server?
I am converting a .riva file to an .rmir file with the command shown below.
QUESTION:  given that program option --gpus 0 is used, do we still need to execute this docker-command on a GPU / NVIDIA server?
docker run --rm --gpus 0 -v $MODEL_LOC:/data $RIVA_SM_CONTAINER -- \
    riva-build speech_recognition \
        /data/rmir/asr_offline_conformer_ctc.rmir:$KEY \
        /data/$MODEL_NAME:$KEY \
        --offline \
        --name=asr_offline_conformer_ctc_pipeline \
        --decoder_type=greedy \
        --ms_per_timestep=40 \
        --chunk_size=4.8 \
        --left_padding_size=1.6 \
        --right_padding_size=1.6 \
        --max_batch_size=16 \
        --nn.fp16_needs_obey_precision_pass \
        --featurizer.use_utterance_norm_params=False \
        --featurizer.precalc_norm_time_steps=0 \
        --featurizer.precalc_norm_params=False \
        --featurizer.max_batch_size=512 \
        --featurizer.max_execution_batch_size=512 \
        --language_code=en-US

